# MVC deciding a View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am deciding upon a view in my ASP.NET MVC scenario. How can Silverlight fit here? Please can you explain in detail and point to some examples.

Comment: Are you asking when you should use SL or how to use SL inside of an MVC view?

Answer (score 0):

1. User sends a request to your controller action passing some parameters
2. The controller receives the request and renders an HTML view embedding the Silverlight plugin passing parameters to it
3. The plugin initializes and renders data